# Ionic5 - struggling with the Picture in Picture mode for a video player app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins, video.js

I am trying to create a video player app in Ionic5. I used the **video.js** package to play the video.

But when I try to get it working for picture-in-picture mode, it just doesn’t work.
I tried console.logging document.pictureInPictureEnabled, it returns false.

I have heard of the cordova-plugin-pip but the npm package page carries no instruction of how to import it or use it.

By the way, **Picture in Picture** mode works when I ionic serve and open it in chrome. It just doesn’t work on the device.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Nope. Nothing yet

Comment: Nope! Nothing yet! As soon as I do, I will post a solution here for sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to execute ionic cap sync in your terminal so your system can accept the plugin.

Later, you have to write in your ts (typescript) file the following:

```
// Between import statements

declare let window: any;

...

window.PictureInPicture.enter(320,240);
```